# numpy.random.choice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

Numpy.random.choice is a nice simple function, that lets you sample an array of ints based on some probability distribution:

```
>>> np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])
array([3, 3, 0])
```

Is there an equivalent in javascript (node js)?

**Note:** I found this package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-weighted-choice` but I don't like creating a hashmap/table every time I need to get a sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this ES6 code:

```js
function randomChoice(p) {
    let rnd = p.reduce( (a, b) => a + b ) * Math.random();
    return p.findIndex( a => (rnd -= a) < 0 );
}

function randomChoices(p, count) {
    return Array.from(Array(count), randomChoice.bind(null, p));
}

let result = randomChoices([0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0], 3);
console.log(result);
```

The `reduce` part calculates the sum of the probabilities. If it is expected that these always amount to 1, then of course that call is not necessary, and `rnd = Math.random()` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)'s [_.sample](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sample) function:

```
_.sample([1, 2, 3, 4]);
// => 2
```