# Change chances of picking a random string

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I would like Anna to have 67% chance of being picked randomly, Bob to have a 30% change, and Tom to have a 3% chance. Is there a simpler way to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
var nomes = ['Anna', 'Bob', 'Tom'];
var name = nomes[Math.ceil(Math.random() * (nomes.length - 1))];
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Can you please tag your post with the programming language what you are using? I assume `JavaScript`.

Comment: Added lenguage and corrected! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654006) I think the following code will work for you:

```js
function randomChoice(p) {
  let rnd = p.reduce((a, b) => a + b) * Math.random();
  return p.findIndex(a => (rnd -= a) < 0);
}

function randomChoices(p, count) {
  return Array.from(Array(count), randomChoice.bind(null, p));
}

const nomes = ['Anna', 'Bob', 'Tom'];

const selectedIndex = randomChoices([0.67, 0.3, 0.03], nomes);
console.log(nomes[selectedIndex]);

// Some testing to ensure that everything works as expected:

const odds = [0, 0, 0];

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

  const r = randomChoices([0.67, 0.3, 0.03], nomes);
  odds[r] = odds[r] + 1;

}

console.log(odds.map(o => o / 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short solution for you:

```js
function pick(){
  var rand = Math.random();
  if(rand < .67) return "Anna";
  if(rand < .97) return "Bob";
  return "Tom";
}

console.log( pick() );
```