# can anyone help me to turn this to js syntax?

Tags: javascript, python

this is my code that I need to convert from Python to JS, I tried a lot of ways I found online but can't seem to find a working one.
the code works in Python but not in JS, the probability to get ['1','1','1'] is 0.2 and so on.
thanks!

```
options = [["1","1","1"],["39","39","39"],["10","10","10"],["19","19","19"],["1","1","1"],"2", "lose"]
result = random.choices(options, weights = [0.2,0.8,1,1,2,75,20])[0]
```

Comment: It would be nice to have an example from Python for what the output should be.

Comment: `options` is correct ... `random.choices` possibly just needs a second argument (without the `weights =` ... or perhaps `weights:[0.2 .... etc]` ... it really depends on how `random.choices` function is coded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy.random.choice in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654006/numpy-random-choice-in-javascript)

Comment: result for example would be: "lose" or "['10','10','10]'

Comment: hey Ronny thanks for the suggest, but it doesn't work

Comment: hey Jaromanda but random.choices is not valid JS

Comment: I didn't know that was a pythin thing, I imagined that code was your attempt at writing  a solution, clearly I was mistaken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```js
var random = {
    int (min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
    },
    choices (options, weights) {
        // find the total weight. Can also be done by looping
        let totalWeight = weights.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        // getting a random number from 0 till totalWeight
        let randomNumber = this.int(0, totalWeight);
        // resetting the totalWeight
        totalWeight = 0;
        for (let i in options) {
            totalWeight += weights[i];
            // once the weight hits the randomNumber, return the element
            if (totalWeight >= randomNumber) {
                return options[i];
            }
        }
        // otherwise, return the last element
        return options[options.length - 1][0];
    }
}
var options = [["1","1","1"],["39","39","39"],["10","10","10"],["19","19","19"],["1","1","1"],"2", "lose"];
var result = random.choices(options, [0.2,0.8,1,1,2,75,20])
console.log(result);
```